# SSRS Report Builder: Creating text color expression based on textbox value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

Is it possible to have SSRS look at the value of a text box after calculating it, and then apply an expression to determine the color of the text?

More specifically, I have a lot of different text boxes that contain custom formulas to calculate percentages. Normally, I would create an IIF statement in the text color expression builder like this:

```
IIF([complex formula]<0,"RED","GREEN").
```

This works fine, but when you have a ton of these textboxes, each with different formulas, it would be much more efficient to just copy one standard color expression into them like this:

```
IIF(This.Value>0,"RED","GREEN")
```

Are expressions like this possible in SSRS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is yes, if you are using a very recent version of SSRS:

```
=IIF(Me.Value < 0,"Red","Green")
```

Link to original article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx)

Hope that helps.

Comment: "if you are using a very recent version" => I wouldn't call SSRS 2005 a "very recent version of SSRS"

Comment: lol, well then I've been missing out, cause that would have saved me so much work in the past :)

Comment: Well, to be more precise, it worked in 2005, then had a bug in 2008 ([Me.Value bug in SSRS 2008](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-us/98f0e6a0-108c-44bb-8730-5e90cf1fa5a4/mevalue-bug-in-ssrs-2008)), which was fixed in 2008R2

Answer (score 2):

It's not as clean, but if you need to refer to a different already calculated cell (or self reference for that matter) you can use

```
=IIF(ReportItems!CellName.Value < 0,"Red","Green")
```

EDIT: This is actually listed in the link @Randall Mathews posted, which I didn't click until I answered.